# Translate UIView animation Swift code to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-animations

I need to translate this Swift code to Objective-C.

```
animationView?.subviews
     .compactMap({ $0 as? RotatedView })
     .sorted(by: { $0.tag < $1.tag })
     .forEach { itemView in
         rotatedViews.append(itemView)
         if let backView = itemView.backView {
             rotatedViews.append(backView)
         }
     }
```

If you cannot convert to Objective-C, please tell me what's happening there, I will convert it.

P.S. `rotatedView` is class of `UIView` and `rotatedViews` is an empty array is kind of `rotatedView` class.

As suggest from @Haris Nadeem i am sharing what i have done till now.

```
NSMutableArray *dummy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(id view in self.animationView.subviews){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[RotatedView class]])
        [dummy addObject:(RotatedView *)view];
}
for(RotatedView *preView in dummy ){
//        if( view.tag>preView.tag){
//            [dummy addObject:view];
//            preView.tag=view.tag;
}
for( RotatedView *iteamView in [rotatedViews addObject:iteamView]){
     if (preView.backView ==  iteamView.backView)
         [rotatedViews addObject:preView.backView];
}
}
```

Comment: Because you need to show us what you have already tried and the problems you are facing. We will not look at code and convert it for you or even attempt to look at it until you have done so first. Please look at the rules and guidelines for asking a question

Comment: @HarisNadeem i looked for compactMap function , first its not available in objective  c and second i could not understand from apple developer. so i am not able convert it. as per my knowledge  $0 is first element of that collection and $1 is send element, append is adding object at end of array. there so much for loop in these code while writing in objective c (according to my understanding) i am confusing. so i ask ask but down-voting result in putting hold on question.

Comment: Let's translated: `compactMap()` see there https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/ why it's used. The `sorted()`, when it's sort according to the `tag` property. The `forEach()` seems an explicit name.

Comment: @Larme thanks buddy. can you explain what these line is :   { $0 as? RotatedView } in context of above.

Comment: Iterate and keep only the objects of class RotatedView.

Comment: @Larme buddy what these line is doing:-   itemView in
                rotatedViews.append(itemView)                             iterating with variable and adding that variable in an array ?? i could not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not giving this line: `var rotatedViews: [RotatedView]()`

```
animationView?.subviews
   .compactMap({ $0 as? RotatedView })
   .sorted(by: { $0.tag < $1.tag })
   .forEach { itemView in
       rotatedViews.append(itemView)
       if let backView = itemView.backView {
           rotatedViews.append(backView)
       }
   }
```

Let's break the chaining, and name some intermediaries variables because doing it in one line is cool, but harder sometimes to debug, and in Objective-C, it will be quite messy 
=>

```
let compacted = animationView?.subviews({ $0 as? RotatedView })
let sorted = compacted.sorted(by: { $0.tag < $1.tag })
sorted.forEach { itemView in
    rotatedViews.append(itemView)
    if let backView = itemView.backView {
        rotatedViews.append(backView)
    }
}
```

So what's happening there:
`compacted`: Keep only the subviews that are of class `RotatedView`.
`sorted`: We sort theses view according to their `tag` properties.
On the last one, you misunderstood completely what is happening.
We had to `rotatedViews` all the previous views of `sorted`, and if they have a `backView` we add it too.

Not tested (written without debugger/compiler/XCode):

```
NSMutableArray *rotatedViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Final array

NSMutableArray *compacted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (UIView *aView in animationView.subviews)
{
    if ([aView isKindOfClass:[RotatedView class]])
    {
        [compacted addObject:aView];
    }
}

NSArray *sorted = [compacted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(RotatedView *view1, RotatedView *view2){
    NSInteger tag1 = [view1 tag];
    NSInteger tag2 = [view2 tag];
    return [@(tag1) compare:@(tag2)];
}];

for (RotatedView *itemView in sorted) //That's equivalent to forEach( itemView in
{
    [rotatedViews addObject:itemView]; //That's equivalent to rotatedViews.append(itemView)
    UIView *backView = [itemView backView]; //That's equivalent to if let backView = itemView.backView
    if (backView)  //That's equivalent to if let backView = itemView.backView
    {
        [rotatedViews addObject:backView]; //That's equivalent to rotatedViews.append(backView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot buddy! For explaining such a great way...  Small correction tag1 and tag2 will be type of NSInteger. And yes it compilable 

Comment: I fixed the `let` -> `NSInteger`, thanks for spotting it.